# Embed flash live feed with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I embed this live feed -- it has Javascript and this `ac_ff_runcontent`:

```
<script src="http://static.awempire.com/Scripts/AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0','width','160','height','120','src','http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','wmode','transparent','flashvars','appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template3/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto','movie','http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed' ); //end AC code
</script>
<noscript>
   <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" width="160" height="120">
       <param name="movie" value="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" />
       <param name="quality" value="high" />
       <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
       <param name="flashvars" value="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template3/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto" />
       <embed src="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" width="160" height="120" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" flashvars="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template3/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto"></embed>
   </object>
</noscript>
```

In this:

```
$(this).html(**'PLACE THE CODE HERE**');

}, function() {

    $(this).html('<img src="' + $(this).attr("title") + '" width="180" height="135"/>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you still interested but you could try an SWF-Wrapper like

http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/

or

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/toolbox/flashembed/index.html